# Struts2 and Hibernate insert operation error

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Struts Problem Report
Struts has detected an unhandled exception: 

Messages: 



FreeMarker template error!

Method public java.lang.String org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw an exception when invoked on org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.acv.in.bean.Student was altered from 294912 to 294912
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${msgs[0][0]} [on line 76, column 25 in org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/error.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public java.lang.String org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw an exception when invoked on org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.acv.in.bean.Student was altered from 294912 to 294912
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:130)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.get(SimpleMethodModel.java:138)
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName.dealWithNumericalKey(DynamicKeyName.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._getAsTemplateModel(DynamicKeyName.java:90)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:188)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:703)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMemberModel.unwrapArguments(SimpleMemberModel.java:85)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:106)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: what could be the possible mistake

Comment: i got it , its due to mismatch of arguments, in primary key type was long ;   in data base INTEGER( in database table ) and it was int  in bean object and student.cfg.xml mapping file.